# How can I incorporate NA removal into aggregate based on a custom function?

Tags: r, function, aggregate, na

This is my first time using any custom functions, so bear with me. I made a function for standard error that I'd like to use with `aggregate`. It worked until I tried to exclude NAs.

Dummy data frame to work with:

```
se <- function(x) sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))
df <- data.frame(site = c('N','N','N','S','S','S'),
                birds = c(NA,4,2,9,3,1), 
                worms = c(2,1,2,4,0,5))
means <- aggregate(df[,2:3], na.rm = T, list(site = df$site), FUN = mean)
error <- aggregate(df[,2:3], na.rm = T, list(site = df$site), FUN = se)
```

So `aggregate` worked before I excluded NAs (e.g. `error <- aggregate(df[,2:3], list(site = df$site), FUN = se)`), and it works when finding the mean (using the rest of the values to take the mean and ignoring the missing value). How can I exclude NAs in that same manner when using my custom `se` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you do not have an explicit argument for `na.rm` in your `se` function. If you add that to your function, it should work:

```
se <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE) {
    sd(x, na.rm = na.rm)/sqrt(sum(!is.na(x)))
}
```

Comment: I tried using this code and got "unexpected bracket" errors.

Comment: I forgot one bracket while copying the code from my script. The edited function should work

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get that part of code to work, but errors are now popping up elsewhere. Does using this method mean I always need to specify `na.rm` whenever I use `se`?

Comment: you can specify a default input for the argument (see the edit above). Then you do not need to call `na.rm = TRUE` in other parts of your code, if that is what you want use.